# Anonymous Facebook post with Google Forms Response

Tags: facebook, google-forms

After having a thoroughly research on google about how to create a confession page as they exist i find zero documentation and mislead answers.

Essentially what i need is from a facebook page that i have to prompt the user to a google form that will fill as he/she find proper and later on the submit button anonymously post the answer to my facebook page.

What i found as solutions are https://automate.io/integration/facebook/google-forms, https://zapier.com that provide you with some days of trial and then you have to pay for a plan.

Isn't there any way around it

Comment: Facebook is not made for posting anonymously.

Comment: Thanks for the en lighting. . Please avoid unnecessary comments!

Answer (score 0):

I manage to establish this anonymous confession page by creating the questionaire in the google forma and save the file to spreadsheet.

The establishment with the facebook page was made through zapier software where i choose the proper specifications that i wanted to make the proper post!